# Stream gate - removing samples from timeline. Pitfalls?

Tags: gnuradio, distortion

I'm working with *gnuradio*. What I want achieve is extract signal from full stream by some kind of stream gate (based on tags) and after that write to file only timeline where signal exists. In my case the time to wait between signals (5-30 min) might be too long compared to signal (~1.7sec). The length of signal may vary around 1.7 sec so i can't use *Tagged Stream* block and all others block based on *packet_length* value.

I write embedded python script - inherite from *basic_block*, implement *general_work*. When "gate" closed I consume *x* samples and return *0*, if "gate" opened - consume *x* and return *y* samples. It seems like work as intended - upstream blocks didn't freeze, downstream processes data.

It seems like there is a some pitfalls in removing samples from timeline as there is not default block in gnuradio that actual "remove" samples. Delay, skip, head and others only change samples value to zero so I have doubts..

My questions are:

1. Is there a right way to remove samples from timeline? Is it the DSP way?
2. If I add waterfall sink after gate it clearly seen by naked eye where gate closed and where opened (I gess when immediately close gate there many freqs generated) Should I use filters in downstream? Or maybe need to implement some kind of "windowing" functionality?
3. Is there any other pitfalls of using "gate" in general? Signal distortion, aliasing.. etc?